# Database design for a social network site. Help!

Tags: mysql, database-design, indexing, normalization, social-networking

I'm  looking for a solution to design a table (using mySQL) for a social networking site in the most efficient way. Here is my current table set-out:

```
User_ID  Peer_ID   Message   
001      002       msg from 001 to 002
001      003       msg from 001 to 003
001      004       msg from 001 to 004
001      005       msg from 001 to 005
002      001       msg from 002 to 001
002      003       msg from 002 to 003
002      004       msg from 002 to 004
002      005       msg from 002 to 005
003      001       msg from 003 to 001
003      002       msg from 003 to 002
003      004       msg from 003 to 003
003      005       msg from 003 to 005
and so on...
```

(up to approx 10,000 member with 9,999 messages to each respective member. ie 100 Mil rows)

I'm aware that one of the first rules of normalization is broken as the User_ID column has repeating values.
I would rather have a unique key index column for the User_ID and utilize Auto_Increment for when a new user registers, resulting in a matrix format. ie. User_ID in a column & Peer_ID in header row.
However in this case up to 10,000 columns would be required (for each Peer_ID) and no way of auto generating a new column as new users register. See below:

```
User_ID  001             002             003             004            005
001      NA              msg:001 to 002  msg:001 to 003  msg:001 to 004 msg:001 to 005
002      msg:002 to 001  NA              msg:002 to 003  msg:002 to 004 msg:002 to 005
003      msg:003 to 001  msg:003 to 002  NA              msg:003 to 004 msg:003 to 005
004      msg:004 to 001  msg:004 to 002  msg:004 to 003  NA             msg:004 to 005
005      msg:005 to 001  msg:005 to 002  msg:005 to 003  msg:005 to 004 NA
and so on...
```

Any ideas on how I can create a more efficient table design?
Thank in advance...

Comment: no, you're right the first time.  so long as the user_id column and peer_id column are foreign keys into some "users" table, then you've got it right, and no *values* are repeated, only *references* are repeating.

Answer (score 2):

You first table design is fine, there's nothing wrong with repeating values from row-to-row. I think you're misunderstanding the concept of repeating groups, which refers to column-to-column repeats. (Which your second design employs.)

See [`http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)

Answer (score 1):

I've done one messaging system. It's interesting if you want to make it like conversation in Gmail and Facebook.

Do you have plan to show messages in a single conversation? If not, it's pretty straight-forward.

You just need a coupole of fileds more. Read/Unread flag and Date/Time.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't just adding a "Reply To" column which maps to another message's primary key allow you to create a daisy-chained Gmail-threaded-affect pretty easily?